# Location.hash убрать #

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, php, хеширование, javascript

Добрый вечер, подскажите  как убрать  из url'a # при location.hash (без перезагрузки страницы..)?
если это не возможно тогда подскажите как через .htaccess (заменить #  на ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственный возможный вариант без перезагрузки страницы — `History API`:

```
history.pushState('',document.title,window.location.pathname)
```

Comment: Это html5 (

Comment: пришлось history.js подключать...